# What do you call it when people lay flowers etc. at a specific place?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call it when people lay flowers, bring toys, light candles at a specific site (near an embassy, for example) to express their condolences with respect to some tragic loss of life (a plane crash, etc.)? Is there some expression in English?

Answer (score 2):

The place could be called a "shrine" or a "memorial".  The expression we use is to "lay flowers"

> Bereaved families should have the default right to lay flowers or other small items at any time at the site of their loved one’s crash, such as on verges and tied to lamp-posts. ([Roadside memorials](http://www.brake.org.uk/help-for-victims/8-services-for-carers/239-memorialadvice#:%7E:text=Flowers%20and%20other%20moveable%20items,and%20tied%20to%20lamp%2Dposts.))

Comment: What do you call the action? Are there alternatives to 'pay respects'?

Comment: "lay flowers", but "pay respects" is good too.  You pay respects by laying flowers.

Comment: "Lay flowers" means "lay flowers". I was asking whether I could express a wider sense